# where method not working properly on laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, where-clause, php-carbon

I'm trying to extract the last user workouts and I don't know why I can't do this. I think I'm doing well. Please, check it out. [image]

Comment: As I see , you are using MongoDB  , Php time and Mongo Time is different. Can you try to use  MongoDate http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php instead of Carbon.

Comment: MongoDB? No, I am not using it. The screen has been captured while  testing on tinker (php artisan tinker)

Comment: I'm assuming you have a relationship named `workouts`. Does this give you what you need: `$user->workouts()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth())->get();`? (note: `workouts()` vs `workouts`)

Comment: Yes, It was that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `where()` method on an Eloquent Collection, not the relationship query.

The `where()` method on a Collection works differently than the `where()` method on a query. For the Collection, the second argument is the value to compare, and the function can only do an equals comparison. The third parameter is a boolean to determine if it is a strict equals (===) or not (==).

To do what you're looking for, you need to call `where()` on the relationship query (and `get()` the results after):

```
// note $user->workouts() is the relationship query
$workouts = $user->workouts()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth())->get();
```

Comment: I swear I did that before but without any results. Perhaps I forgot the `get()` method at the end. I appreciate your explanation. Thanks very much.